# Function composition and differentiability

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

This problem asks for an example of functions $f$ and $g$ such that $g$ takes on all values, $f \circ g$ and $g$ are differentiable, but $f$ is not differentiable. I'm having trouble jumping straight to an example, but I bet this might involve a floor or absolute value function. A hint would be preferred over an explicit answer.

Comment: To be clear do you want $f$ and $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ with $g$ surjective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about 
$f(x) = x^{1/3}$ which is not differentiable at $0$ but takes on all values, $g(x) = x^3$ which takes on all values and is differentiable? Then $f \circ g(x) = x$ is clearly differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example would be a composition of the absolute value function and some positive function, say $x^2$. If you need $g$ to be surjective, consider $g(x)=x+5,g:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: I believe he wants $g$ to be surjective.

Comment: @Seth Oh.${}{}$